# Añadir espacio en blanco dentro de cadena de caracteres en varchar de abecedario seguida de digitos, despues de las letras

Tags: postgresql

Tengo un reto, en una variable de direcciones urbanas (dir_urb), y requiero normalizar todas las direcciones como (dir_normalizada)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Encontré esta solución, para las entradas 1 y 2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_cambiar_text(_expr varchar)
  RETURNS varchar AS
$func$
SELECT string_agg(CASE WHEN $1 ~ '^\w'
                       THEN txt || COALESCE(v.por_reemplazar, t.a_reemplazar) 
                       ELSE COALESCE(v.por_reemplazar, t.a_reemplazar) || txt END
                , '' ORDER BY rn) AS result
FROM ROWS  FROM (
          regexp_split_to_table($1, '\W+')
        , regexp_split_to_table($1, '\w+')
       ) WITH ORDINALITY AS t(a_reemplazar, txt, rn)
LEFT   JOIN sinonimos v ON v.a_reemplazar = NULLIF (t.a_reemplazar, '')::varchar
$func$  LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Esta me permite "estandarizar" el tipo de vía cuando esta separada por un espacio con el numero de esta vía.

Pero, para las variaciones de (alpha+digi) debería tomar el valor (alpha+' '+digi), no he podido

Aunque he intentado con:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('CALL32 5A 125', '((?=[^ ]*[a-z])(?=[^ ]*[0-9])[^ ]+)',  'New_value', 'gi');
```

Esta no me permite realizar una consulta sobre 'New_value"

```
select regexp_split_to_array('CALL32 5A 125 asdf546!', '\\s+');
```

Esta debería puestamente coloca un espacio en comas, pero, al variar \s+ por ^[0-9] no me realiza ninguna tarea